# rmmovl dynamic number of bits

Tags: assembly, y86

I know that rmmovl can be used in the following way:

```
rmmovl %ecx, 4(%edx)
```

But how can I dynamically set the number of bits to move down the stack (4 in this case)? I've tried setting a variable with the value I want to shift to, such as `rmmovl %ecx, %edi(%edx)`, but this is not working.

Comment: Add `%edi` to `%edx` using a separate instruction first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to manually set %edx to contain the offset. We can save the value of %edx on the stack and restore it afterwards, so its original value is not affected.

```
pushl %edx             # save current value of %edx
addl %edi, %edx        # add %edi to %edx
rmmovl %ecx, (%edx)    # store value of %ecx into %edx with offset %edi
popl %edx              # restore old %edx
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the question.  Analytica's answer is quite right if you were simply looking for a way to perform a variable offset (btw, you could, in principle and not recommended, hack the Y86 code on the fly, building the offset as you go along, since Y86 has no overwrite protection and does not distinguish between data and programs.)

However, you write "...set the number of bits to move down the stack (4 in this case)?"  Unless this is simply a typo, you are asking a somewhat broader question (btw, manually manipulating the stack is not recommended.)  For completeness, I offer two programs that address your question(s).

The first program, Program 1, demonstrates variable offset.  The second program, Program 2, demonstrates stack manipulation through variable offset.  It should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
.pos 0x0100
stack:

.pos 0x00a0
rangestart: .long 0xAAAAAAAA
            .long 0xBBBBBBBB
            .long 0xCCCCCCCC   # Target for substitution in Program 1
            .long 0xDDDDDDDD
rangeend:   

.pos 0x0000
#
# Program 1
#
# Simple program showing how we can "improvise" variable offset in rmmovl
# Our goal is to replace 0xCCCCCCCC with 0xFFFFFFFF in the range from 
# .. rangestart to rangeend and preserving whatever temporary register 
# .... we use for the offset
#
Program1: irmovl stack, %esp # Set stack pointer
irmovl 0xFFFFFFFF, %ecx      # Stuff we can easily recognize
irmovl rangeend, %edx        # Target area that we will negatively offset from

irmovl $-8, %edi             # Set offset value -8

pushl %edx                   # Save current value of %edx
addl %edi, %edx              # Add offset to %edx
rmmovl %ecx, (%edx)          # Store value of %ecx into %edx with offset 
popl %edx                    # Restore old %edx
jmp Program2

#
# Program 2
#
# Simple program showing how we can manipulate the stack using offsets
# Manipulating the stack is NOT recommended.
# Our goal is to push some easily recognizable stuff on the stack
# ... and change it afterwards 
#
Program2:
pushl %edx                # Save current value of %edx
pushl %edx                # .. and %eax
irmovl 0xFFFFFFFF, %edx   # Stuff we can easily recognize
pushl %edx                # Push it
irmovl 0xEEEEEEEE, %edx   # Stuff we can easily recognize
pushl %edx                # Push it
irmovl 0xDDDDDDDD, %edx   # Stuff we can easily recognize
pushl %edx                # Push it

irmovl 0xAAAAAAAA, %eax   # Stuff we can easily recognize
irmovl $4, %edi           # Set offset value 4 (replace 0xEEEEEEEE)

rrmovl %esp, %edx         # Get stack 
addl %edi,%edx            # .. and offset

rmmovl %eax, (%edx) # Store stuff we recognize into offset to stack 

popl  %edx                # Bypass 
popl  %edx                # .. junk
popl  %edx                # .... on stack
popl  %edx                # ....... and restore old %edx
popl  %edx                # ......... and %eax 

halt                      # Finito!
```